# how to get how many node with certain attributes with DOM

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I have a task to parse an XML file with JDom in Eclipse. When I started to create the code, my code is only sufficient to get the length(how many) node with Tag name model. The task is more specific, I need to get the length of the node with tag name model which has attribute type. How should I modify my code to get the result?

This is part of my XML file

```
<container>
  <models>
    <model id="FM1" type="BoQ">
      <meta
       <phase phaseDesc="PRCR>SLCT>"/>
    <domain domainCode="SPM.BOQ.RFP "/>
    <levelOfDetail levelOfDetailCode="[4]"/>
  </meta>
</model>

<model id="FM2" type="Object">
  <meta>
    <phase phaseDesc="PRCR>SLCT> "/>
    <domain domainCode="BIM"/>
    <levelOfDetail levelOfDetailCode="[4] "/>
  </meta>
</model>

<model id="FM3">
  <meta>   
    <phase phaseDesc="PRCR>SLCT>"/>
    <domain domainCode="SPM.QTO"/>
    <levelOfDetail levelOfDetailCode="[5]"/>
  </meta>
</model>

<model id="FM4" type="BoQ">
  <meta>   
    <phase phaseDesc="PRCR>SLCT>"/>
    <domain domainCode="TSM.TSC"/>
    <levelOfDetail levelOfDetailCode="[3]"/>
  </meta>
  </model>
 </models>

  <linkModels>
    <linkModel id="LM1" type="QuantitySplit">
  <meta>
    <info>
      <i k="ModelName" v="Linkmodell"/>
    </info>
    <domain domainCode="LKM.QSP" domainDesc="Link Model"/>
  </meta>
  <models>
    <model id="FM1"/>
    <model id="FM2"/>
    <model id="FM3"/>
    <model id="FM4"/>
  </models>

</container>
```

public class xmldom {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document xmlDoc = getDocument("./src/MMT_Angebot_Anfrage.xml");

    System.out.println("Root: "+ 
            xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList model = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("model");



    System.out.println("Number of Models " +
            model.getLength());

    String elementPhase = "phase";
    String elementDomain = "domain";
    String elementLOD = "levelOfDetail";
    String attrPhase = "phaseCode";
    String attrDomain = "domainCode";
    String attrLOD = "levelOfDetailCode";

    getElementAndAttrib(model, elementPhase, elementDomain, elementLOD, attrPhase, attrDomain, attrLOD); 
}

private static Document getDocument(String docString) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        factory.setValidating(true);

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        return builder.parse(new InputSource(docString));

    }

    catch(Exception ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }


    return null;
}

private static void getElementAndAttrib(NodeList model,
        String elementPhase, String elementDomain, String elementLOD,
        String attrPhase, String attrDomain, String attrLOD) {

    try {

        for(int i=0; i < model.getLength(); i++){

            Node modelNode = model.item(i);

            Element modelElement = (Element)modelNode;


            NodeList phaseList = modelElement.getElementsByTagName(elementPhase);

            NodeList domainList = modelElement.getElementsByTagName(elementDomain);

            NodeList lodList = modelElement.getElementsByTagName(elementLOD);

            Element phaseElement = (Element)phaseList.item(0);

            Element domainElement = (Element)domainList.item(0);

            Element lodElement = (Element)lodList.item(0);

            NodeList elementList = phaseElement.getChildNodes();


                System.out.println("=================================================");               
                System.out.println(attrPhase + " : "+ phaseElement.getAttribute(attrPhase));
                System.out.println(attrDomain + " : "+ domainElement.getAttribute(attrDomain));
                System.out.println(attrLOD + " : "+ lodElement.getAttribute(attrLOD));

        }
    }

    catch(Exception ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: How can we tell you what modifications you should do when you don't show us any of your code?

Comment: Ah, yes..you're right..I already put the code..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the number of `<model>` elements that contains the type attribute? If, so XPath is the most suitable tool.

```
XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

Double num = xp.evaluate("count(//model[@type])", doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
```

Btw, you are using DOM, not JDOM.

Comment: Thank you very much @forty-two, it works..you just made my day!!. And yes, I use DOM instead of JDOM, thanks for the correction.